# sbt resolution taking too long

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a Scala project which is built on a Jenkins farm. Sometimes the build takes a very short but somethings it takes too long to resolve.

```
00:02:26.699 [A[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.objenesis#objenesis;2.6 ...[0m
00:02:46.700 [A[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.objenesis#objenesis;2.6 ...[0m
00:03:02.563 [A[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.objenesis#objenesis-parent;2.6 ...[0m
00:03:30.563 [A[2K[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mResolving org.objenesis#objenesis-parent;2.6 ...[0m
```

What can be the reason for resolution taking long?
I am using 0.13.12 sbt.

My sbt command looks like

```
sbt -Dsbt.repository.config=proxy_repositories -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true '-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|*.abc.com' -no-share clean test project_A/assembly
```